# I am getting this error. Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateReqiured does not exist

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, model, controller

I am getting this error for validation of form.

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateReqiured does not
>   exist.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRequired;

class EventController extends Controller
{

protected $events;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->property = new Event();
}
/* get all data */
public function getEvents()
{
    $events =Event::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view ('navbar.viewevents',compact('events'))
    ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
}

//view event form
public function viewEventForm()
{
    return view('navbar.events');
}

/* Creating Events */
public function addEvents(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request,[
        'e_name' =>'required',
        'venue' =>'required',
        'e_image' =>'rquired|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'e_status' => 'required'
        ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return \Redirect::back()
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
                            }

    $events = $this->property->addNewEvent($request);
    return \Redirect::back()
            ->with('message','Team member added successfully');
 }
```

please help to get rid of this error. I had also tried code below.

```
 $this->validate($request,[
    'e_name' =>'required',
    'venue' =>'required',
    'e_image' =>'rquired|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    'e_status' => 'required'
    ]);
```

I am getting same error for methods. I this code after removing use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRequired; but same error is appearing. Anyone can help highly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Typo: `rquired` should be `required`

Comment: After correct spellings i am getting same error.

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRequired;`? Where does that line come from? No such file exists

Comment: Yes tried this thing as well but same error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRequired;
```

Try:

```
use Validator;
```

Also, on Laravel 5, you can validate with in the request object (no imports needed):

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```