# How to use exclude_if on Laravel on Store

Tags: php, laravel

When i try to use excude_if, Laravel returns me this message :

"message": "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateExcludeIf does not exist.",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException"

That's a part of my code :

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class StoreDmLog extends FormRequest
{

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'fname' => 'required|max:20',
            'eventdate' => 'required|before:now|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            'title' => Rule::in(['Mr', 'Ms', "Mrs", 'Mr & Mrs']),
            'fname' => 'required|max:20',
            'lname' => 'required|max:20',
            'samename' => 'required|boolean',
            'res_title' => 'exclude_if:samename,true',       
            'checkout' => 'date_format:Y-m-d|required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58771310/10573560

Comment: `Exclude If` was added in Laravel 6, so make sure you're using at least that version.

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",